# Celery: Passing Docker variable through CMD in Dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, celery

Docker run will not start a conatiner with this command.

`celery -A proj worker -Ofair --concurrency=600 --without-gossip --time-limit=500 --pool=gevent -l info -n $(uuidgen -r)`.

However, it will start with this command:

`celery -A proj worker -Ofair --concurrency=600 --without-gossip --time-limit=500 --pool=gevent -l info -n celery1`

This is on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. If I run that command in the terminal, celery will start with no problem.

Dockerfile

```
#Download base image ubuntu 16.04
FROM python:3.6-slim

COPY . .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 80 443 6379 9200 9300

CMD celery -A proj worker -Ofair --concurrency=600 --without-gossip --time-limit=500 --pool=gevent -l info -n $(uuidgen -r)``
```

I expect this to generate a uuid for the celery instance as it does when run in the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s because uuidgen doesnt exist on the docker image.